# @FullCalendar: reassign events array in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in Angular 8, I have assigned it the events array, it displays all the events of a user,

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
initialView: ‘dayGridMonth’,
showNonCurrentDates: false,
fixedWeekCount: false,
events: this.calendarEvents
};
```

now I have a dropdown list where user can select a category, depending upon the value selected by user I need to assign specific events array,
I was trying it in an if condition like below,

```
if(this.timeline_val == ‘STTR’){
this.calendarOptions = {
initialView: ‘dayGridMonth’,
showNonCurrentDates: false,
fixedWeekCount: false,
events: this.calendarEvents1
};
```

But it is not getting overwritten with events1 values. The new event list added is not reflecting in the calendar.

I even tried to reassign the new arraylist to previous array in the if condition, but it is not working.

```
 if(this.timeline_val == 'ABC'){
      this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents2; }
```

Can you please help? How do I reassign events array in Angular?

Comment: If you pass a static array of events to fullCalendar, it stays that way - a static copy of the list. Updating the original list (as you've tried to do) has no effect on the data held inside the calendar - because it's a copy, not a reference to the same object.

Comment: You'd probably be better using the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) pattern, and inside the callback you can check the timeline value, and decide which events to return. Then, when your dropdown list is changed, you can simply call [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) which will trigger your pre-configured function, and update the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ADyson

I installed `@fullcalendar/interaction` , as it was not given for installation in the [article](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular), but was included in the imports, not sure if it matters.
And I created another simple project and below code worked,

```
if(this.timeline_val == ‘STTR’){
  this.calendarOptions = {
  initialView: ‘dayGridMonth’,
  events: this.calendarEvents1
};
```

also added below,
`deepChangeDetection="true"`

I am guessing something from my original code was stopping the events from being updated.